# where python saves the result of the last operation?

Tags: python, c, api

Where does Python save the result of the last operation?

For example, If the last operation was `math.sqrt(9)`, where does Python save the value 3.0?

Or if the last operation was `"hello " + "world!"`, where is the value `'hello world!'` saved?

I want to approach this from a C program (using Python's C API) and pass this value to a `char*` variable.

Comment: Maybe you could give a specific example of what you would like to do, and what part of it should be done in C and what part in Python.  Why is this tagged C#?

Comment: I have a C program. The program runs some python scripts and what i need is a way to capture, in a C code, all the outputs which python makes ... for GUI purpose

Answer (score 6):

Python itself does not save the result of the last operation. The Python REPL saves the last result in `_`, but you would not be using the REPL in this situation.

Comment: @user534976: REPL means Read-Eval-Print-Loop, which here refers to Python's interactive console or command line shell. This is generally not involved when you execute a Python script unless you do so from the shell by `import`ing it.

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't.

It sounds like you want to call Python code from C, and use the result in the rest of the C code.

What you do is write a **function** in the Python code, and use its **return value**. It will be passed back as a `PyObject*` from the C API function that calls the Python function.

Comment: i need to capture pythons output from C code to a string. How do i implement such function ...?

Comment: When you call the python function from your C code, it will return a PyObject*. Use the API to check that this represents a string (because it could be any Python object - whatever got returned from the function), and extract a C string.